# Diferença entre cache de primeiro e segundo nível do NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Ao pesquisar sobre cache dentro do NHibernate, eu me deparei que existem dois níveis de cache que podem ser utilizados, o de primeiro nível e o de segundo nível.
Achei artigos com implementações de ambos os tipos e tudo mais, porém eu gostaria de saber qual é a real diferença dos dois. Por que escolher um ou o outro?

Comment: Em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337072/what-is-first-and-second-level-caching-in-hibernate

Comment: Neste link, o autor dá uma ideia de quando utilizar o segundo cache: http://blog.streamlinelogic.ca/2007/03/nhibernate-cache.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- O cache de **primeiro nível** nada mais é do que a sessão (definida pela interface `ISession`) que armazena as entidades (registros) carregados na memória. Também é chamado de *cache de transação*. Este cache previne que um mesmo registro (identificado pela chave primária) seja carregado duas vezes, reduzindo assim o consumo de memória e solicitações ao banco de dados, além de rastrear as alterações realizadas no mesmo.

Saiba mais em: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-overview

- O cache de **segundo nível**, também denominado de *cache de query's*, é opcional e pode ser habilitado nas configurações do NHibernate. Este cache permite que você registre query's que são realizadas frequentemente, armazenando o seu resultado e evitando que estas sejam executadas novamente no banco de dados. Um exemplo clássico de uso deste cache seria a listagem dos itens em promoção apresentados na página principal de e-commerce (que são os mesmos para cada usuário que visitaria o site).

Saiba mais em: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache